# how to write daily backup job for elasticsearch in production environment, we are using docker image and kubernetes for containerized platform

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, openshift

I am new in elasticsearch and we want to write daily backup job in our production environment ,In our production environment we are using openshift and kubernetes, and our elasticsearch deploy as a docker container in kubernetes environment,I have some idea about elasticsearch snapshot strategies but how 
to implement for daily elasticsearch backup job in containerized environment.

Comment: Checkout the Elasticsearch [Curator](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/snapshot.html). Combining with the use of crontab, you can create snapshot periodically.

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation and @Tim Wong post, you can use for this task "**Scheduled Backup using curator**".

More information how to combine snapshot with cronjob [here](https://advishnuprasad.com/blog/2018/10/07/kubernetes-elasticsearch-scheduled-backup-and-retention-using-curator/) and [here](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/install_config/aggregate_logging.html#configuring-curator).

Please share with your results and findings.

Answer (score 0):

you need to write a cronjob and in that cronjob, you should use the host as service name it will take backup. (as per kubernets view)